# Search ignores leading/trailing underscore?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, underscore

I tried searching for `__LINE__` and all results had "line", but not `__LINE__`. There are questions on SO containing `__LINE__`, which I found by searching with other criteria.
Search strings like "const_cast" work, so underscores are not entirely ignored. Maybe it is ignored at the beginning and end of the word (to work with italics/bold)?

Comment: I'm observing the same behavior when trying to search for `__str__`.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest search changes, this is now handled much better, for example:

- Search for [__LINE__](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=__LINE__)
- or more specifically (only *exact* matches), use quotes: ["__LINE__"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22__LINE__%22)